# how to get current minutes php

Tags: php, time

i need a simple script to print the current minutes.
but ONLY the minutes(or seconds ^^).
**in php**

Comment: Please define what you mean by "current minutes". Number of minutes since the program started? Since the epoch? Or do you mean 27 from 14:27?

Answer (score 46):

use `date('i')` to show minutes or `date('s')` for seconds.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php